# How to display the information registered in the database in the editor?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

If you can see in the following textarea you already have information or content, this data is obtained from the database, it should be noted that this information is shown in the textarea is when information is going to be edited or updated.

But the problem is that the information that is in the textarea is not shown in the editor, what changes must be used so that the content of the textarea is shown in the editor.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.13.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<textarea id="detail" name="detail" ><p>The information get from database...</p></textarea>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('detail');
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear.  I am having trouble understanding what you mean

Comment: @GitauHarrison friend, that the information here: `<textarea id="detail" name="detail" ><p>The information get from database...</p></textarea>` does not show when loading the editor `CKEDITOR`